# ASP.NET - Gridview - OnRowCreated Event triggers with delay

Tags: asp.net, performance, datagridview, production-environment

Context:

Slowness on page filled with data grid and image controls.Upon analysis found "OnRowCreated" grdview event is triggering with delay of about 30 to 40 seconds approx, clueless abt it considering the fact no update at coding functionally for the past 2 years, except for environmental(OS upgrade to Win 2008 R2 with regular microsoft updates) and infra upgrades.

My Analysis so farr...:
Considering the fact there was no updates/ patch releases functionally for past 2 years and application was running fine only until recently slowness popped up,  I am sure it is an environmental related issue that could me causing slowness so focused analysis on this front but in vain.

So somehow I have to prove its and environmental issue with concrete proof, I created logs for each event/method (Start & End) with time and found one particular method which is triggered on  "**OnRowCreated**" gridview event is triggered with delay and all other methods are all fine including DB updates and retrievals .

### Clueless about what is causing this delay all of a sudden*(is it due to environmental changes like microsoft upgates related to .Net etc???)* . please help. Code snip are as follows.

**Design Page Source(ASPX File):**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTrans" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="931px"
                                                        CaptionAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" OnRowCommand="gvTransCommand" OnRowCreated="gvTrans_RowCreated"
                                                        OnRowDataBound="gvTrans_RowDataBound" CssClass="grid" Height="150px">
                                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheader1" />
                                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridcell" />
                                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridcell2" />
                                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridseletedrow" />
                                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        <Columns>
```

---

*Method defnition in ASPX.VB page:*

```
Protected Sub gvTrans_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

            If (Not Information.IsNothing(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(e.Row.DataItem)) AndAlso Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(NewLateBinding.LateIndexGet(e.Row.DataItem, New Object() {"ShowAtSelectedRecord"}, Nothing), "1", False)) Then
                Me.gvTrans.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex
                e.Row.CssClass = Me.gvTrans.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass
            End If
            Dim button As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lnkGridItemId"), Button)
            button.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "triggered with delay"? How are you measuring this delay?

Comment: @mason : I built the page  to write logs with timestamp at the start and end of each method and found the delay. Sample log segment is as below in comment

Comment: Date        : **10/20/2017 4:20:18 PM**
User ID     : 0
Error Desc  : BalancingAmount.aspx.vb - UpdateAmount Ended 
---
Date        : **10/20/2017 4:21:56 PM**
User ID     : 0
Error Desc  : BalancingAmount.aspx.vb - _gvTrans_RowCreated Function_ Started 
---
Date        : **10/20/2017 4:21:56 PM**
User ID     : 0
Error Desc  : BalancingAmount.aspx.vb - _gvTrans_RowCreated Function Ended_